# CI3 hook only work on local but not on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So my team have cloned a project that have a hook that can track the activity of the users like anything that they POST or GET. The previous project have work perfectly on local and on server. But on the recent project, it only work normal when I run it on local. But on server the hook only track user when they log out.

here's the hooks.php "application/config":

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
'class'    => 'Activity_user',
'function' => 'log_activity',
'filename' => 'log_activity_user.php',
'filepath' => 'hooks',
// 'params'   => array('red', 'yellow', 'blue')
```

);

here's the log_activity_user "application/hooks/":

```
class Activity_user {


function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->library('session');
    $this->CI->load->library('lactivityuser');
}

public function log_activity() {

    $post = $this->CI->input->post();
    
    $get = $this->CI->input->get();
    

    $timezone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta');
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimeZone($timezone);
    $result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   

    if(count($post) > 0){
            

            if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/login')) {
                $data = array(  
    
                    'email' => $_SESSION["email"] ?? $post["email"],
            
                    'menu_name' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
                    
                    'activity' => 'melakukan login',
                   
                    'created_date' => $result,
                    
                );
            }else if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/Log_data')) {
                $data = array(  
    
                    'email' => $_SESSION["email"] ?? $post["email"],
                    
                    'menu_name' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
                    
                    'activity' => 'Melihat Log Data',
                    
                    'created_date' => $result,
                    
                );
            }else if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/History_IO')) {
                $data = array(  
    
                    'email' => $_SESSION["email"] ?? $post["email"],
                   
                    'menu_name' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
                  
                    'activity' => 'Melihat History IO',
                    
                    'created_date' => $result,
                    
                );
            }else if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/Dashboard')) {
                $data = array(  
    
                    'email' => $_SESSION["email"] ?? $post["email"],
                  
                    'menu_name' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
                   
                    'activity' => 'Melihat Dashboard',
                    
                    'created_date' => $result,
                   
                );
            }else if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/api/rule')) {
                $data = array( 
                    'email' => ' ',
                    'menu_name' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
                    'activity' => 'Rule',
                    'created_date' => $result,
                );
            
            }else if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/API/Rule')) {
                $data = array(  
    
                    'email' => ' ',
                  
                    'menu_name' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
                   
                    'activity' => 'Rule',
                   
                    'created_date' => $result,
                    
                );
            }
            else{
                $data = array(  
    
                    'email' => $_SESSION["email"] ?? $post["email"],
                    'menu_name' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
                    'activity' => json_encode($post),
                    'created_date' => $result,
                );
            }
            $this->CI->db->insert('tb_activity_user', $data);
        
    }else if(count($get) > 0){
        $data = array(

            'email' => $_SESSION["email"] ?? $post["email"],
            'menu_name' => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
            'activity' => json_encode($get),
            'created_date' => $result,
        );
        $this->CI->db->insert('tb_activity_user', $data);
    }
  
    
}
```

}

edit: they have enable the hook to TRUE in the config file

Comment: What is in the error logs?

Comment: on the server or on local?